# Excel Charts: Latency Budget / Time Management

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a Latency Budget. This is a graph which lists each step in a process with a bar proportional to the size of the time/latency associated with this process (green), as well as additional time margin (red).

I have a table where the first column is the process, the second column the time/latency and the final column the time margin.

Is there an automatic way to create a graph similar to the one I made below, which is updated whenever the table is changed? Stacked bar charts go in the right direction, but I cannot make it work completely the way I want.

I would also hope to be able to easily add another process/row to my table and have the chart updated to account for this. If there is no such chart available in Excel, does anyone know a programme which would work?

[image: latency budget]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest 'cheat' to achieve a chart with the necessary properties is to create one additional column in the table. Potentially, the font colour of this column can be set to 'white' to make it seem non-existent to final users.

This third column would have a 'zero' as a first entry. From the second entry onwards, the value is the sum of the values from the first column&first row of the table to the second column&current row. The code in the second row of this third column is the following:

```
=SUM($B$2:C2)
```

This can then easily be dragged downwards if new rows are added to the table.

Finally, a Stacked Bar Chart can be created using 3 Series, each with the list of processes and one of the columns as a data-input. Make sure the third column is the last series.

Now the colour and border of Series 3 can be set to white. In the 'Format Axis' of the process names, 'Categories in reverse order' can be ticked, as well as 'Horizontal axis crosses: at maximum category' to achieve a similar look to the graph in the post above.

[image: Latency budget]

Answer (score 1):

With a change in order and an added column with, in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUM(C3:D7)
```

the result from plotting a Stacked Bar from selecting (say A2:D7) in the example is:

[image]

after selecting the left-hand of the three series and choosing No fill, choosing colours to suit, deleting gridlines, legend and Title, and  increasing Gap Width to 500% and other settings as default. The exception being that to obtain the small green element for the top bar I added `50` to the data.

The chart responds to changes in the data.